# How do I move a buffer into the data segment using gcc inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, operating-system, inline-assembly

I want to try to use the `ide_read_sectors` and `ide_write_sectors` from OsDev's PCI IDE driver implementation here, https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI_IDE_Controller#Read.2FWrite_From_ATA_Drive.

To move the buffer (a `u8* buffer`) into the data segment using

```
asm volatile("mov %0, %%CS"
            : :"r"(buffer));
```

It crashed the program.

My overall code is based on this tutorial, https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial. To clarify, I want to move something like a string to `cs`.

Comment: All that inline assembly that deals with ES is all nonsense. It can be removed. The GCC compiler requires the environment to already be CS=DS=ES=SS.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah, but I wan't to move that buffer to the segment. Can you give me an example how?

Comment: You don't move a buffer to a segment like that. The exception you are getting is because you can't even update CS with a `mov` command on processors later than the 8088. All the segments are the same. It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve. A bad tutorial on OSDev is sending down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @MichaelPetch How am I supposed to do it then? I'm trying to move a buffer into the segment, then call a function that writes that segment to the disk.

Comment: CS=DS=SS=ES and all are using flat Descriptors in your OS. You do not need to copy between segments because all the segment point at the same data. So es:buffer is the same as ds:buffer is same as ss:buffer is same as cs:buffer.

Comment: That tutorial should never have done anything with ES. I can only gather that whoever wrote it originally had code that was running in 16-bit mode and they had no idea what they were doing when they changed to 32-bit (or 64-bit code). There is even a comment in the code about the ES stuff being wrong/buggy. Although OSDev is a good place to get info there is a lot of bad  code on that site.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't want to copy between segments, I want to copy between a buffer in c and a segment.

Comment: The buffer is in a segment. I think you need a better understanding on how the x86/x86_64 architecture works. What you are doing is totally unnecessary. Anyway, I'll let someone else followup and help you. I can only go so far with this.

Comment: This makes zero sense.  You can't use a pointer as a segment selector value (index into the GDT), and you definitely don't want to modify the *code* segment; that would be a jump if it wasn't the same as the old value.  (Which is why `mov reg, %cs` isn't available on CPUs after 8086, only far-jmp).  Agreed with Michael: find a different tutorial and learn some more about x86, or better just use a flat memory model and forget don't touch segment registers except for entering protected / long mode.